# How to find access_token expired or not in Onedrive?

Tags: api, access-token, onedrive

In Onedrive I am able to use their Live SDK API and get the Access_token and the filepicker for my users is also working properly.

But, every time a user tries to attach a file I am calling the API to get the Access_token.

Is this a problem, when more number of users try to call this API every time they try to attach the files( did Microsoft has a limit for number of API call).

Also, If i try to use Refresh_token for Access_token using WL.offline_access scope how would my app know the Access_token is expired?

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to add logic to your code to see if the user is already has a session occurring.  You can do this this by adding WL.Event.subscribe and checking for "auth.statusChange".  If the users status has changed at any point, it will call the function to check the users current status (i.e. connect, notConnected, and unknown) by calling WL.getLoginStatus.   WL.getLoginStatus will also return the users session object (access_token, expires_in, etc) if you want to use any values there.

Your code will look something like this.

```js
< script type = "text/javascript" >

  WL.Event.subscribe("auth.statusChange", chkStatus);

function chkStatus() {

    WL.getLoginStatus(
      function(response) {
        if (response.status == "connected") {

          document.getElementById("info").innerText = "You're signed in";
        } else {
          WL.login({
            "scope": "wl.skydrive_update"
          });
        }
```

More info on WL.getLoginStatus can be found at https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/hh550842.aspx.  I hope that helps.